# Spring @RestController is not mapping URL with Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kotlin

I've created a **Kotlin gradle** project using [Spring IO](https://start.spring.io/).

Created a `Controller` class with a method to return a `String`.

When I build and run the project I'm getting 404 error. Looking at the logs I don't see the URL mapping to the method.

If I use Java instead of Kotlin it works fine. I am using JDK 10.

**Code**

```
@RestController
class IslandController

@GetMapping("/greeting")
fun getMessage() =

        "hello world"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include your function into the controller class:

```
@RestController
class IslandController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    fun getMessage() = "hello world"
}
```

Comment: curly braces are optional in Kotlin

Comment: @chattambigeek from the [Kotlin reference documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html): _"if the class **has no body**, curly braces can be omitted."_